# How to mount a NFS Datastore on a linux vm

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, nfs, datastore

I have a vsphere private cloud with 3 nodes and 10 datastore.

I want to use 1 of the datastore as a mounted NFS (for storage) across multiple VMs.

Can this just be mounted normal within the /etc/fstab like -

ds:///vmfs/volumes/datastorepath

Is this even possible to do, if so how would I do this.

The option I considered was creating a VM with a large disk and running it as a NFS Server, but this seem stupid, considering the datastore are NFS.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to mount the VMFS datastores directly within the guest OS.

An option you could do:

- Deploy a virtual NAS of your choice (OpenFiler, FreeNAS, etc)
- Configure *that* VM with storage space from one of those datastores
- Configure the VM to serve that datastore space as NFS storage to the VMs